# Why Akka waits in this example?

Tags: akka

I am reading [this](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html) Akka document, and I don't understand how the *master* wait for the `Result` message.

At the bottom of the code, the *master* received a `Calculate` message

```
// start the calculation
master ! Calculate
```

But the `!` message is a **tell** message which means it is asynchronous. Why the application does not exit after that line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default dispatcher for an Akka `ActorSystem` uses daemon threads and thus the JVM does not exit unless that `ActorSystem` is shut down. That's why the test will continue to run even though that `tell` is the last line that `App`.

Comment: So it is the JVM feature, not the framework that make it wait...any idea how can I control it?

Comment: You control it by explicitly shutting down the actors you don't need and/or shutting down the actor system at the end of your program (shutting down the system shuts down all actors as well).